# Como converter CamelCase para snake_case em C#?

Tags: c#, camel-case, snake-case

Gostaria de saber como faço para converter uma string com *CamelCase* para *snake_case* em C#.

Por exemplo:

```
 EuAmoCsharp => eu_amo_csharp
 SnakeCase   => snake_case
```

Comment: Qual código você tem até o momento?

Comment: Estou aprendendo C# agora. Não tenho a mínima ideia de como fazer.

Comment: No [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/machupicchubeta/10016121) tem mostrando o inverso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seria algo assim:

```
string stringSnake = string.Concat(
                         stringCamel.Select((x, i) => i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString().ToLower() : x.ToString().ToLower())
                     );
```

[Fiz um Fiddle pra você](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8n6G3C).

Explicando:

`string` é uma enumeração de `char` no C#. Então posso usar:

```
stringCamel.Select()
```

Uma das maneiras de usar `Select` é especificando no predicado duas váriáveis, sendo `x` o caractere atual da iteração e `i` o índice dessa iteração.

O condicional é mais simples de entender:

```
i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString().ToLower() : x.ToString().ToLower()
```

Confiro se `i` é maior que zero e se o caractere atual é maiúsculo, isto porque não quero escrever `_` antes do primeiro caractere.

Se o caractere é maiúsculo, escrevo `_` e o caractere em minúsculo. Caso contrário, apenas escrevo o caractere.

Preciso manter `ToLower()` nos dois resultados por causa do primeiro caractere.

Comment: Cigano, SE eu pedir pra você me explicar esse código, você o faria? Eu sei fazer CamelCase para snake_case em c#, mas eu nunca faria deste modo. me explica por gentileza?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Com certeza.

Comment: Interessante a resposta. +1

Comment: Eu não tinha entendido o i > 0, ficou fácil de entender depois que você explicou,obrigado mesmo. @Cigano Morrison Mendez

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez muito bem explicado. Apesar de que nessa pergunta eu evitei o "code golf", mas ficou bem pequeno o código.

Comment: Um detalhe importante: palavras que forem "all caps", vão retornar algo como `"CPF" -> "c_p_f"`. Para resolver isso, é só verificar se `!stringCamel.All(c => char.IsUpper(c))` :) https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sx2nJL

Answer (score 3):

Só a título de curiosidade, dá pra fazer com regex também, mas é um tanto mais lento

```
string stringSnake = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=.)([A-Z])", "_$0", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Comment: Só lembrando que este é um pouco mais lento, mas funciona bem.

Comment: Aliás, **bem mais lento**.

Comment: Por que é mais lento? Regex é mais lento em geral?

Comment: Por que é mais lento? @jbueno

Comment: Não sei te responder com certeza @PauloHDSousa, mas geralmente trabalhar com regex é mais custoso. Nesse caso em específico eu testei a minha solução e a do Cigano, por isso sei que é mais lento...

Comment: Fiz uma pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138705/fazer-substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-strings-com-regex-%C3%A9-mais-lento-do-que-replace