# Fazer substituição de strings com Regex é mais lento do que Replace()?

Tags: c#, .net, string, regex, desempenho

Digamos que eu queira fazer algo como nesta pergunta:

[Como converter CamelCase para snake_case em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138690/como-converter-camelcase-para-snake-case-em-c/)

Teve algumas respostas, mas quero destacar essas duas.

Resposta 1

```
string stringSnake = string.Concat(
                     stringCamel.Select((x, i) => i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString().ToLower() : x.ToString().ToLower())
                 );
```

Reposta 2

```
string stringSnake = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=.)([A-Z])", "_$0", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Alguns contribuintes do S.O. falaram que a resposta 2 é **bem mais lenta**, gostaria de saber o por quê?

- É por ser em regex?
- É o regex que está "mal feito"?
- Regex é lento em geral?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Medir sempre

Para saber sobre velocidade sempre tem que medir o caso real. E pode mudar dependendo de uma série de questões. Pode ser diferente se rodar em plataforma diferente, se os dados forem diferentes, se for usado em conjunção com outras coisas e principalmente depende da versão da linguagem ou biblioteca que está usando. O que vale hoje, pode não valer amanhã.

## Qual é mais rápido

Não dá para afirmar que um RegEx sempre será pior que um `Replace()`, até porque o a função de troca pode ser mal usada e não fazer da melhor maneira possível. Se ficar aplicando o `Replace()` várias vezes na mesma *string* pode ficar mais lento.

Mas em condições normais será mais rápido porque essa função vai mais direto ao ponto. Por mais que o algoritmo do RegEx seja bem feito é uma solução geral que tenta resolver qualquer problema, ele tem que tentar ver cada caractere se atende todas situações que ele pretende trabalhar.

Medir performance de RegEx não é tão intuitivo para afirmar que sempre será mais lento. Mas minha experiência é que a maioria dos casos é mais lento mesmo, em alguns casos as diferenças são brutais.

O RegEx pode ganhar se tiver várias modificações, porque ele pode ir fazendo tudo em um passo só. Principalmente se a *string* do padrão a ser achado já estiver compilada (pelo menos no C# há compilação do padrão de texto e é feito um cache). Se usar várias vezes, ele pode se tornar interessante. Claro que depende também da qualidade do compilador da expressão. Se ele puder fazer algumas otimizações, ajuda bem.

[Compilar ajuda, mas não faz milagre](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-performance).

## Outras técnicas

É possível usar outras técnicas que não sejam essas duas que podem dar um resultado ainda melhor, por exemplo fazer uma análise de caractere por caractere e tomar a decisão em cada caso. Isso pode ser mais simples ou mais complicado de fazer dependendo do caso. Essa técnica pode fazer um "replace" de várias coisas em um passo só.

Já vi muita gente ter performance ruim porque não entende o funcionamento do *garbage collector*, o problema nem sempre está na manipulação da *string* em si, mas do gerenciamento da memória. Pode ficar trágico em grandes volumes.

**Posso garantir que o programador sempre conseguirá um resultado melhor na mão do que um RegEx**, desde que ele use a técnica adequada (`Replace()` ou não) implementada da forma correta. Se dará mais trabalho, se ficará feio, se ficará confuso, se terá outros problemas, é outra questão, pode acontecer ou não. RegEx não é tão simples, não fica bonito e é confuso, a questão é quanto.

Sempre é possível produzir uma expressão RegEx que não seja trágica, mas pode dar tanto ou mais trabalho que escrever um código na mão.

No [exemplo específico tem uma resposta com código idêntico, com uma comparação de performance feita no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18781533/221800).

Veja uma [comparação feita pela Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/debuggingtoolbox/comparing-regex-replace-string-replace-and-stringbuilder-replace-which-has-better-performance?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Note que o `StringBuilder()` que todo mundo acha melhor para essas coisas se saiu pior. Nem sempre o que parece ser o melhor é de fato.

Um [exemplo real postado por um dos fundadores deste site](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-performance/) citando o problema que a Microsoft enfrentou.

Tem um site que ajuda entender RegEx e mostra as armadilhas que pode cair, entre elas o [*backtracking*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Eu acho estranho as pessoas que falam em legibilidade defender RegEx.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu tinha lido esse artigo do backtracking, muito obrigado por me responder, aprendi bastante. Vou pensar 2x antes de usar regex de novo.