# Qual a diferença de uso entre os métodos matches() e find() da classe Matcher?

Tags: java, regex

Estou tentando entender a diferença de uso destes dois métodos da classe [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), mas não consegui entender bem pela descrição da documentação que diz:

> **public boolean matches()**
>   Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.
>
> **public boolean find()**
>   Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.
>   This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous match.

Qual a diferença de uso entre estes dóis métodos? Se possível, gostaria de ver a diferença exemplificada.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`matches()` vai dizer se a String inteira bate com o regex do pattern;
`find()` vai dizer se tem o regex na String, e se chamado novamente, se o regex ocorre novamente, e assim por diante.

Veja a saída desse código no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/jD8oSw)

```
String text =
            "This is the text to be searched " +
                "for occurrences of the http:// pattern. Find http:// again";

    String patternString = ".*http://.*";    
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);    
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());

    String patternString2 = "http://";    
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(patternString2);    
    Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(text);
    System.out.println(matcher2.matches());
    System.out.println(matcher2.find());
    System.out.println(matcher2.find());
    System.out.println(matcher2.find());
```

Comment: Por que o ultimo find() retornou false?

Comment: Porque só tinha duas vezes o padrão "http://" na String. Então as 2 primeiras vezes o find() acha o padrão, na terceira vez ele não acha mais.

Comment: Quer dizer que o find() procura a primeira ocorrencia que encontra da regex dentro da string e quando encontra, para e retorna true, e na proxima vez, ele ignora as ocorrencias que já achou?

Comment: Na prática, é isso. O find() começa no começo da String na primeira vez que é chamado, e a cada chamada subsequente começa no primeiro caracter depois do último padrão encontrado (se encontrou algum).

Answer (score 11):

[`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) procura por toda a *string*, ou seja, o padrão que você está procurando deve ser exatamente igual à *string* sendo usada para procurar. É como se estivesse usando um igual.

[`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) procura por aquele padrão na *string* e se achar qualquer parte que "bata" com o padrão está bom pra ele. Ele usa um *substring*. É como se usasse um `LIKE` do SQL. Ou é como se usasse um `^` no começo e um `$` no fim em uma expressão regular.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Matcher fonte = (Pattern.compile("test")).matcher("teste de regex");
        System.out.println(fonte.find());
        System.out.println(fonte.matches());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/e8ZA2Z). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jkuykuqj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/RegExFindMatches.java).

Comment: Consegui visualizar, um tem que bater a string toda, o outro vai procurando por "pedaços" que batam com a regex.

Answer (score 4):

Vamos pegar a expressão para casar `(bb|([^b].|b[^b]))*`. Essa expressão pode ser entendida como "dois bê ou não dois bê" aplicado à [estrela de Kleene](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240086/64969).

> **Estrela de Kleene**, tl;dr: repetição do elemento quantificado pelo `*`, pode do aparecer zero ou mais vezes

Por definição, exige-se que exista um número par de letras para casar com essa expressão. Isso significa que `bbab` casa com a expressão, porém `bbaba` não casa.

Inicialmente, isso implica que `matcher_bbab.matches()` retorna verdade, `matcher_bbaba.matches()` retorna falso, e `matcher_bbab.find()` e `matcher_bbaba.find()` retornam verdadeiro também. Se você aplicar novamente para procurar com `find()` vai falhar em ambos os casos.

Agora, tomemos a mesma expressão só que sem a estrela de Kleene: `(bb|([^b].|b[^b]))`. No caso de `bbab`, será possível realizar duas vezes o `find()` com sucesso, porém não será possível ter um `matches()` com sucesso; o terceiro `find()` resultará em erro. O mesmo acontece para `bbaba`.