# Por que a classe Matcher não retorna o número de grupos corretamente?

Tags: java, regex

Após a pergunta "[Qual a diferença de uso entre os métodos matches() e find() da classe Matcher?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242446/28595)", continuei testando essa classe para entender seu funcionamento, mas me deparei com um comportamento estranho.

Ao tentar identificar o número de grupos encontrados na string por uma determinada expressão regular, o retorno sempre é 0, mesmo que haja ocorrências da ER na string.

No exemplo abaixo([online](https://ideone.com/e2QEMl)):

```
String text = "um2tres4cinco6sete8";

String regex = "[0-9]";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
System.out.println("Total de grupos: " + m.groupCount());
```

O retorno é:

> ```
> 2  
> 4  
> 6  
> 8  
> Total de grupos: 0
> ```

No [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Q06WIE/1) também é exibido dessa forma.

Segundo a documentação do método [groupCount()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount--):

> **public int groupCount()**
>   Returns the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern.

Se a função desse método é retornar o total de grupos capturados, por que ele retorna 0 e não 4 neste exemplo? Ou estou interpretando alguma coisa de forma equivocada desse método?

<sub>P.S.: Se possível, gostaria de uma explicação com exemplos.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O resultado é zero pois não tem nenhum 'capturing group' na sua expressão regular. Veja a documentação do [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical):

> (X)  X, as a [capturing group](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg)

mas `"[0-9]"` não contem nenhum trecho entre '(' e ')'.

Além disso note a documentação do [group()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group--), não confundir com o método `group(int)`:

> Returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match.

ou seja, retorna o que foi encontrado, não (necessariamente) o que corresponde a um dos grupos.

Com o seu exemplo, se a espressão fosse `"([a-z]*)([0-9]*)"`, os resultados do primeiro `find` seria:

- `group = "um2"` - trecho encontrado
- `groupCount = 2` - número de grupos 1:`([a-z]*)`, 2: `([0-9]*)`
- `group(1) = "um"`
- `group(2) = "2"`

Comment: Se não tem, como o find encontrou 4 ocorrencias?

Comment: Continuo sem entender a diferença.

Comment: Agora entendi. Que mancada da Sun/Oracle, esses nomes então só levam a quem tá aprendendo a se confundir.