# Como saber o número de ocorrências possiveis encontradas pelo método group() da classe Matcher?

Tags: java, regex

Após a pergunta "[Por que a classe Matcher não retorna o número de grupos corretamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242713/porque-a-classe-matcher-n%C3%A3o-retorna-o-n%C3%BAmero-de-grupos-corretamente)", foi explicado que o método `groupCount()` na verdade retorna o número de grupos de filtros na expressão regular, e na pergunta "[Qual a diferença de uso entre os métodos matches() e find() da classe Matcher?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242446/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-uso-entre-os-m%C3%A9todos-matches-e-find-da-classe-matcher)" me foi explicado duas formas de como identificar ocorrências da Expressão Regular(ER) em determinada string.

Ainda tomando o exemplo de uma destas perguntas, através do método `group()` eu consigo recuperar a ocorrência atual na string, e com um loop e o método `find()`, eu consigo recuperar todas as ocorrencias encontradas na string:

```
String text = "um2tres4cinco6sete8";

String regex = "[0-9]";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

O retorno disso é:

> ```
> 2  
> 4  
> 6  
> 8
> ```

ou seja, o `find()` encontrou 4 ocorrencias da ER usada.

Minha duvida é saber como identificar o número de ocorrencias possiveis sem ter que recorrer a laços e incrementos com o método `find()`. A classe **`Matcher`** ou alguma classe relacionada a ela possui algum método que retorne esse número de ocorrências sem recorrer a loops ou "workarounds" com iterações ou a unica forma é incrementando num laço somente?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme esta [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46049447/1518921) o máximo que vai conseguir antes do Java 9 é criar um método ou usar `replaceAll` para contar com o método `String.split`

### Antes do Java 9

Pode adicionar a sua classe ou criar uma classe que contenha um método estatico como:

```
static int countMatches(Matcher matcher)
{
    int counter = 0;

    while (matcher.find())
      counter++;

    return counter;
}
```

Para usar chame assim:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
System.out.println(countMatches(m));
```

Ou:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
System.out.println(SuaClass.countMatches(m));
```

Ou usando .replaceAll para contar as ocorrências na string:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
System.out.println(m.replaceAll("\0").split("\0", -1).length - 1);
```

> **Nota:** `\0` significa "nulo", ou seja esse caractere raramente vai existir em uma ocorrencia, mas pode haver exceções, então pode tentar alternativas a ele.

---

### Java 9

No Java 9 foi adicionado o método [**`public Stream<MatchResult> results​()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--)

Com ele você poderá contar o `Stream<MatchResult>`, deve ficar assim:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
System.out.println(m.results().count());
```

Comment: Mas ai ta usando laço, eu gostaria de saber se a classe Matcher armazena isso de alguma forma ou se alguma classe equivalente me retorna isso.

Comment: @Articuno Java 9 `Matcher.results​` ?! Vou de qualquer forma analisar a classe antes do Java  9 e a doc para ver se é possivel pegar os valores internos, talvez extendendo a classe exista alguma propriedade interna acessivel. Já te confirmo.

Comment: Não tinha visto essa do Java 9, alias, nem  me lembrava q já tinha Java 9 kkk. Mas parece que anterior não tinha nada, vasculhei a classe matcher e Pattern e elas não armazenam isso, só a posição atual do find() na string.