# Validar um texto com regex

Tags: java, regex

Eu possuo o seguinte código:

```
final String msgRegex = "Produto [a-Z0-9À-ú, ]*";
        final String msg = "Produto Soja";
        if (msg.equals(msgRegex)) {
            System.out.println("Verdadeiro");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Falso");
        }
```

No caso é como se ele desconsiderasse a `regex` que está em msgRegex. Como faço pra ele validar retornando true no equals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua regex tem um errinho que não permite compilá-la, que é a range `a-Z`, corrigindo este erro, o correto seria utilizar `Pattern` e `Matcher`, e checar se há algum match entre o padrão e a string com o método `find()`:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public classe RegexTest {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        final String msgRegex = "Produto [a-z0-9À-ú, ]*";
        final String msg = "Produto Soja";

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(msgRegex);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(msg);

        if(m.find()) {
             System.out.println("Verdadeiro");
        }else {
             System.out.println("Falso");
        }
    }
}
```

Funcionando no ideone: https://ideone.com/CS9vL8

---

Segue algumas questões relacionadas que vale a pena ler a respeito do uso da classe `Matcher`:

- [Qual a diferença de uso entre os métodos matches() e find() da classe Matcher?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242446/28595)
- [Por que a classe Matcher não retorna o número de grupos corretamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242713/28595)
- [Como saber o número de ocorrências possiveis encontradas pelo método group() da classe Matcher?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242740/28595)

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.